# remove a single post_meta

Tags: metabox, post-meta, customization

I created a plugin that has multiple meta boxes. One meta box saves a single record by using `update_post_meta()`. Another meta box saves multiple record by using `add_post_meta()`.

I do not have revisions turned on in the post_type.

How would you `delete_post_meta()` a single specific record in the meta box that uses `add_post_meta()`? Best practice advise is needed.

If you're going to send the whole `$post->ID` and it will get the array of records, how can I detect the specific `meta_key` set to be deleted?

Here is the code on github: 
https://github.com/fritzdenim/stec-events/blob/62d5c641622f75a610da09462260f09713f0abab/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say there is barely enough information in the question to speculate on an answer but it sounds like to me that...

If your data is saved in individual key/value pairs then [`delete_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta) will do it. You would pass the function a post ID and a key name: `delete_post_meta(1,'keyname');`. It will delete the whole key/value pair.

If you have multiple bits of information saved as a serialized array/object then `delete_post_meta` ***will not work***. You will need to pull the data for the key you want with `get_post_meta`, alter the array/object in `PHP` to remove the key/value you want to delete, and then save the altered data with `update_post_meta`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Comment: Where would the delete_post_meta() get the $post_id from? I'll place the code anyway... just a sec.

Comment: Your description makes me think `delete_post_meta` won't work, but the short answer to that question is that you have to give the post ID to the function.

Comment: If you're going to send the whole `$post->ID` and it will get the array of records, how can I detect the specific `meta_key` set to be deleted?

Comment: You also give `delete_post_meta` a key but take a careful look at the answer. `delete_post_meta` will delete the entire key. That is why I said `delete_post_meta` will not work. You need to pull the data, process it in PHP and then put the data back.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work because there are 2 hooks for publish_post and save_post. Maybe this will work in a json setting where you update one field.

Comment: Backup, forget this part "This is just a concept to discuss. So, no code really needed." and [edit] you question with your code. Code _is_ necessary.

Comment: It may seem to be harder to add postmeta if one meta box deals with `add_post_meta` and another `meta box` deals with `update_post_meta` because it does not support good practice. In having multiple posts in one meta and single post meta in another, using json to store data in one field would be easier. Manipulating the json data is also easier rather than dealing with `add_post_meta` and `update_post_meta` if this is the case.